# ModuleNotFoundError: Shipping Python modules to Spark cluster nodes using conda environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Spark version: 3.2.1

pySpark script was not able to resolve python modules in conda environment.
Any help is really appreciated

Detailed steps...

1. conda env prepared on laptop

```
conda create -y -n myconda-env -c conda-forge -c anaconda python=3.8 conda-pack grpcio 
conda activate myconda-Env
python -m pip install PyHamcrest
python -m pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
conda pack -f -o myconda-env.tar.gz
```

2. Uploaded myconda-env.tar.gz to my Notebook environment in the cloud
3. Create SparkSession with conda environment

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("SPARK_URL")
conf.setAppName("MyApp")
conf.set('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client')

# Conda environment
conf.set('spark.archives', 'myconda-env.tar.gz')

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

4. pySspark script

```
# Python script files import modules in conda environment
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("searchproto.zip")
```

4. We get below error when python scripts in searchproto.zip try to import modules in conda

```
y4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 7) (10.201.37.44 executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 619, in main
process()
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 611, in process
serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 259, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1562, in takeUpToNumLeft
File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 74, in wrapper
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "", line 1, in
File "", line 8, in rdd_func
File "", line 259, in load_module
File "./searchproto.zip/searchproto/StudentEvents_pb2.py", line 5, in
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:555)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:713
```

Comment: what do you mean by `Uploaded myconda-env.tar.gz to my Notebook` ? Have you uploaded file to DBFS, or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt for the reply. I created myconda-env.tar.gz on my laptop then uploaded file to cloud where my Notebook is running.

Comment: If it’s DBFS, then you need to provide full path…

Comment: I assume you are referring to path on the executer. If so, since we are using Bitnami spark image not sure how to get the myconda-env.tar.gz file path on executor.

Comment: But why are using Databricks as Tag if you are using something else?